# Background image positioned at '0% 0%' w.r.t screen and NOT the parent element, why?

Tags: html, css, background-image

To better understand what I am saying, [head over to this pen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/tnJjH) which shows the HTML & CSS code I am using ([with preview](http://codepen.io/joe/full/tnJjH)).

Take a look at the CSS code for the second background image:

```
.top-navbar-channels a {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Z1YZt.png');
    background-position: 112px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 35px;
}
```

What I don't understand is, the background is being positioned w.r.t the screen and not the parent element. I tried `display: block;` on the parent element and the element itself, but nothing changed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `background-attachment: fixed`, the origin of a background image is *always* the viewport. That's why it starts at, and is positioned with respect to, the top left corner of the screen.

Since you're already affixing the navigation bar to the top of the page, you do not have to apply fixed positioning to the background images. It should be safe to remove `background-attachment: fixed` from both of your navigation links and adjust the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Okay, that worked great. And thanks for the to-the-point explanation. **EDIT:** Here's [the modified fiddle/pen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/yGcLt) with the fix.